# How to correctly write this in set notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have defined the following set

$$\{\mathrm{skill}_i^j\mid 1\leq i\leq 100\text{ and }1\leq j\leq n\}$$

I'm unsure if this notation is correct. My intention is to say that the set contains $n$ elements ($j$ ranging from $1$ to $n$). For each element (skill) "$i$" can be a value between $1$ and $100$.

What is the correct way of writing this in mathematical terms?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write

> The set of skills is $\{\text{skill}_j\in[1,100]:1\leq j\leq n\}$.

Or, the constraint that each value be between $1$ and $100$ could also be a separate sentence, e.g.

> The set of skills is $S=\{\text{skill}_1,\ldots,\text{skill}_n\}$. Each skill satisfies $1\leq \text{skill}_j\leq 100$.

However, if I can attempt to guess that your intention is for there to be multiple people and you want to refer to each person's skills, I would suggest that you say that $P$ is the set of people, and for each $1\leq j\leq n$, there is a function $\text{skill}_j:P\to[1,100]$ that takes a person $p\in P$ as input, and outputs the number $\text{skill}j(p)$ representing the strength of $\text{skill}_j$ in person $p$, which satisifes $1\leq\text{skill}_j(p)\leq 100$.